# Why delay() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9gvrj/):

```
$('#click').click(function() {
  $('#delay').delay(2000).css('background-color', '#c30000');
});
```

Why does the `delay()` call not delay the `css()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/delay/ and http://api.jquery.com/queue/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
        $('#delay').delay(2000).queue(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#c30000');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: GMTA - but I was too slow: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/ZWcud/

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript's setTimeout():

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#delay').css('background-color', '#c30000');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method **is best for delaying *between* queued jQuery effects**. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So, basically, in your scenario a timeout is a better approach than a delay as you're not between effects.

Answer (score -1):

`delay()` is for [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) only.

Use a basic `setTimeout` call instead.

Comment: jQuery UI only? I believe it works for normal jQuery effects, provided you are in an animation queue.

Comment: @alex: I thought all effects came under jQuery UI. Seems not though!

Comment: Well jQuery has an [effects section in their documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). You don't *need* [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to do effects.